# generate mono energetic photons

Tags: particle-physics, simulations

I am working on a project on BESSIII and I am using BOSS frame work . I want to generate mono energetic photons but I don't know how can I do it. any help is  appreciated.

Comment: This is an incomplete question . are you talking of this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_Electron%E2%80%93Positron_Collider_II .   BES III? and you have to give a link for BOSS.  One generates monoenergetic photons with lasers. If you mean gammas with specific energy you should say so.

Comment: @annav I think the question might be about generating monoenergetic photons in a simulation framework. One would imagine this is to characterize something like detector acceptance/efficiency or trigger performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to *simulate* monoenergetic photons and their interactions, there are several software frameworks (e.g. [GEANT4](https://geant4.web.cern.ch/)). If what you is to simulate the interaction of a photon with the atmosphere, you have programs like [CORSIKA](https://www.ikp.kit.edu/corsika/)